# POST variables are never set

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I have form with 2 inputs, country name and country rating (0-5) and submit button to add country. When button is clicked it executes addCountry function.
**I always get an error as message and I don't know why $_POST['country'] and $_POST['ratings'] are not showing.**
Function looks like this:

```
 <script>
 function addCountry(){  
 var $country="country";
 var $ratings="ratings";
  
$.ajax({  
          
type:"POST",  
url:"../actions/addCountry.php",  
data:{ $country: "country", $ratings: "ratings" },  
success:function(result){  
    alert(result);  
}  
  
});
}
 </script>
```

Php script should get country name and rating, it looks like this:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['country']) && 
isset($_POST['ratings'])){

$country= $_POST['country'];
$ratings = $_POST['ratings'];

 echo $country;
 echo "is country. You rated it: ";
 echo $ratings;
}
else{
    echo "Error";
}
 ?>
```

Html looks like this:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"src= "../actions/mapData.php"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery 
 3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 90%; height: 20%;"></div>
 </body>

<body>
<form autocomplete="off" method="POST">
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:100%;">
<input id="country" type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country">
<label for="ratings"> Rate this country: </label>
<select id="ratings" name="ratings"> 
  <option value="one"> 1 </option>
  <option value="two"> 2 </option>
  <option value="three"> 3 </option>
  <option value="four"> 4 </option>
  <option value="five"> 5 </option>
</select> 
</div>
 <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add Country" onclick="addCountry()"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Typo. You are sending keys with names that start with dollar signs and omitting them when reading from _POST

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. I have another question. How can I pass value from <input id="country"... > to ajax data

Comment: You have the keys and values backwards: `{ country: $country, ratings: $ratings }`

Comment: @Aplexas `$("#country").val()`

Comment: You can also use `$("form").serialize()` to get all the form fields.

Comment: You should also change the button to `type="button"`. Otherwise it will reload the page.

Comment: Thank you all so much. It works now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your script.

```
<script>
 function addCountry(){  
 var $country="country";
 var $ratings="ratings";
  
$.ajax({  
          
type:"POST",  
url:"../actions/addCountry.php",  
data:{ country: $country, ratings: $ratings },  
success:function(result){  
    alert(result);  
}  
  
});
}
 </script>
```

The data passed to the page is in the form `name : value` and you were giving it wrongly.